# Comparison of simple User Regeistration by PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

A simple user registration may be completed by PHP (framework: Codeigniter,etc..) and Javascript.Following is simple flow:

#### PHP

1. A registration view with form input(user_name,e-mail,password)
2. post the data to an controller to validation
   -Pass, redirect to a completion view
   -Failed, go back to the registration view with some alert strings.

#### Javascript

1. A registration html with input text(user_name,e-mail,password)
2. Validation could be done by Javascript directly before submit; Alert strings could be
   generated by Javscript. Even submission could be done by ajax. Then redirect to the
   completion page.

I found myself code more javascript less PHP. Even the user registration could be done without the "form" tag,right? I am afraid of some parts I had miss or ignore.
Could someone gives me an simple comparison of good/bad parts about these two methods?

Comment: What is the reason that you are not using free platforms like Drupal, Wordpress or joomla where login and user accounts can be handled easily?

Answer (score 3):

User registration details **have** to be stored on the server. You can use any language you like there, JavaScript (node.js is the current preferred way to achieve that), Perl (PSGI/Plack), Python (WGSI), C# (ASP.NET), PHP (mod_php), whatever. If you did it entirely with client side JavaScript, then the registration would exist only for a particular browser (which makes it rather pointless for almost anything on the WWW).

You can do a lot of things with client side JavaScript.

You can test if the data enter by the user conforms to the requirements you've set (such as "usernames contain only ascii alphanumeric characters").

You can't stop data that doesn't conform to those requirements being submitted to your server though - everything outside your server is beyond your control. Users can edit your pages in their browser as much as they wish. Client side validation is a convenience to the user (giving feedback without a server round trip and page reload), nothing more.

You can use Ajax instead of an HTML form … but there is no reason to do that. It just adds an unnecessary dependancy on JavaScript. That doesn't mean Ajax can't be useful, you could use it to ask the server if a username was already taken while the user is filling out the rest of the form.

Comment: Can you be more precise about why AJAX for form submitting is an unnecessary overhead? The process is, in general, a good way to receive messages without refreshing the page, whether they're negative or positive. Plus using JavaScript to submit forms is (from what I've heard) a decent way to give bots a bit of a pain in the ass. Anyway good answer!

Comment: I didn't say "unnecessary overhead". I said "unnecessary dependancy on JavaScript". I also didn't say "form submitting", I said "instead of an HTML form". It stops people from submitting the form if the [JS fails](http://digital.cabinetoffice.gov.uk/2013/10/21/how-many-people-are-missing-out-on-javascript-enhancement/) for **any** reason. It might kick bots, but it also kicks humans. Registration forms are unlikely targets for drive-by bots anyway, and a targeted bot will by able to deal with the JS logic easily.

Comment: I ment to go for "unnecessary dependancy on JavaScript" but alright, point taken about people disabling JavaScript. But I'm not so sure if registration forms are unlikely targets for drive-by bots, I've seen many cases wherea common forums get filled up by bot-generated users.

Comment: JavaScript fails for reasons other than people disabling it. Network failures for example. And the keyphrase there is "common forums". The bots are targeting particular forum software, both for registration and posting.